# Android App runs but doesnt appear on Homescreen

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle, android-manifest

When I run the app from Androidstudio on emulators or real devices the app comes up and runs properly but it isn't visible on the homescreen (or any others).
It does also appear in Settings/Apps.
No errors appear. All advices in the internet didn't help me unfortunately
I tried to rename to App too, wipe all emulator-data.
With or without signing it doesn't make a difference.
Get's reproduceable on other developers environment.
Did compare with another App which appears normally on the homescreen.

Android Gradle Plugin Version 7.2.1
Gradle Version: 7.4.2
Android Studio Chipmunk, 2021.2.1 Patch 1

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="********">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/icon_round"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

Comment: Is there maybe another App installed with the same name? Maybe an older version of the app?

Comment: Do you have a work profile active?

Comment: Try changing android:launchMode="singleTask" to android:launchMode="singleInstance" and also verify if the app is completely uninstalled by going to mobile phone's apps section.

Comment: thanks a lot for your advice - I have wiped all emulators/phones before install it again, no work profile active and if singleTask or singleInstance doesnt matter. I plan to setup the project again, by copying contents by contents and checking meanwhile if it still works